# Salesforce Marketing Cloud mobilePush iOS Not Opted In with Variant Opt-Out Source

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush, react-native

Hi Experts,

I have developed an app using Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK for React Native (source: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk).
Android is working perfectly for mobilePush from Marketing Cloud. 
However, problems occured when I develop the app in iOS.

I have provide APNS Certificate for Sandbox & Production for push service.

When tried using .ipa and install into iphone device, the result is this:

[image]
Opt Out Source: "Service Feedback"

Then when tried to install using TestFlight, there are 2 results occured without changing anything in different devices:

[image]

Opt Out Source: "User Disabled Push"
[image]
Opt Out Source: "Missing or Invalid Device Token"
Can please help why this errors occured and how to solve?

Steps that I have done:
1. Create Production APNS Certificate Push Notification for SFMC
2. Use .ipa and TestFlight to install the app
3. Enable push notification in XCode

Really appreciate for your help :)

Comment: Lyon, did you get this to work?

Comment: I see the internal case is closed.  What was the resolution?

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a certificate issue.  Please review the documentation and update your certificate accordingly (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-provision.html)

Comment: Bill, some mobile contacts have the above issue for my setup and I'm trying to figure out why.  The interesting thing is that my setup works for majority of android + ios devices, only a handful of android device suffering from "Missing or invalid Device Token" rendering not getting any push notification originated from SFMC.

Comment: Have you enabled logging and what do the logs say on an affected device?  What does the output from the "get SDK state" method report on an affected device?  Have you opened a case through your support representative?

Comment: opened a case asking the precise state "Missing or invalid device token" for the 3rd time.  Hope I would get a satisfactory response.

thanks for the suggestion on capturing logs on affected device. Let me see what I can do about that.

Comment: Tell the support representative to at-mention me directly.  I will look through the case as soon as they do.

Comment: Bill Mote, thanks in advance.  Do you work for Salesforce?

Comment: Yes.  Specifically, I work on the team that writes the SDK you're having issues with.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, I will reach out thru SF support.

Comment: They have at-mentioned me and I'm engaged.

Comment: Any updates on this @BillMote? Having the same issue now on iOS production. Thanks

Comment: What update would I add?  You have simply set up your certificate incorrectly.  This is not a server or SDK issue.  We have almost 2 billion devices successfully getting push messages :)

Comment: @codeguy open a support ticket and have them at-mention me.

Comment: @BillMote had to wait for someone to come back so I could access support but managed to sort it today, Apple issue not SF. thanks though.

Comment: ye sorry @BillMote, very new to push and went onto my iMac and generated  a signing request, uploaded to Apple then worked fine, not sure why same process from Macbook was not working.